# Storing pointer references within a class: good programming practice?

Tags: c++, pointers

In some code I have been working on, I am passing pointers into classes that aren't necessarily managed specifically by the class to which they are passed. If the class is destroyed then I check to see if the pointer's memory has or has not already been deallocated. The problem I have is that, if a pointer is deallocated and set to NULL before the class's destructor is called then I end up with a dangling pointer. The class ends up seeing the pointer is still non-NULL and tries to delete it which causes a segmentation fault. The best solution I could think of for this is to store the pointer by reference as shown below:

```
class PtrReferenceClass {
 public:
  PtrReferenceClass(int*& i_) : i(i_) {}
  void run() {
    if(i == NULL)
      cout << "pointer is null\n";
    else
      cout << "pointer isn't null\n";
  }
  int*& i;
};

int main() {
  int* i = new int(5);
  PtrReferenceClass test(i);
  test.run();
  delete i;
  i = NULL;
  test.run();
  return 0;
}
```

As expected, the output is: 
*pointer isn't null*  
 *pointer is null*

Ofcourse when the pointer isn't store by reference I end up with a dangling pointer.

My question is as to whether or not this is generally considered to be a good programming practice. Are there any drawbacks to this solution or is there a better convention?

Comment: This is not good practice, use smart pointers instead, or clarify WHO is responsible to manage the ressource and make sure that the ressource isnt deleted while there are still users out there.

Comment: Just think of the case when you create a pointer, store the reference somewhere else and you exit the execution scope. "And all hell breaks loose..:)". I would use this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm

Comment: Thanks so much for all the insight! I tend to agree about smart pointers, and will definitely be using them more in future projects. In the project I'm working on, I'm using a purely virtual base class rather than an integer. I've found that I run into compilation issues when I try to initialize it's pointer reference to NULL. I'll update my question to include more details and what I end up doing to resolve the segmentation fault soon.

Comment: I found for my application that setting the pointer to NULL from outside of the class whenever it is deleted is suitable. The thing is that I need to cast the pointer to whatever type it is before I delete it. And if it's a default type then it gets deleted within the class that owns it, otherwise it needs to be typecast before it gets deleted. Sort of a mess, thanks again for the insights!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointers to automatically null when object is deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627686/pointers-to-automatically-null-when-object-is-deleted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon what you are trying to accomplish.
If you want the memory around for your class use C++11's `std::shared_ptr` everywhere instead of an int*.
If you don't need the memory around for your class use C++11's `std::weak_ptr`.

As far as holding onto pointers in a class, that's not bad if they're wrapped in one of C++'s pointer wrappers. You can just hang onto raw pointers, but in general you should only do that if speed is an extreme concern.

Comment: Guess what's inside `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`...

Comment: Sugar and Spice and Everything Nice?

Comment: Double indirection (probably actually a pointer to pointer, instead of reference to pointer, to allow reseating, but that doesn't really change anything does it).

Comment: Yeah basically both of these are templatized container classes for a pointer. That's what makes them a bit slower, cause as you suggest I have to do 2 dereferences to get to the target rather than 1. But the class wrapper also provides a lot of safety, like guaranteed cleanup and safe sharing of pointers.

Comment: Right... so the ultimate answer to the question asked is "It's useful, and the best practice is to put it into a reusable library, so you only have to worry about the intricacies *once*.  And that reusable library already exists."

Comment: If I understand your statement as it pertains to this question, you're suggesting that @mastershake86 should not hold raw pointers as members of a class, but rather use auto pointers. Which I agree with in general. But are you going a step further to say that there is never a case where a class should have a raw pointer, even for purposes of speed?

Comment: There is no speed advantage to a raw pointer over the correct pointer-wrapper abstraction.  I would call it a smart pointer, but some abstractions (especially the non owning pointer) have no additional behavior of their own. Still it is worth using a named abstraction, since a raw pointer could be a handle to one object, or a vector iterator, or a list iterator.

Answer (score 2):

You could check for NULLness in the destructor of PtrReferenceClass. A much better alternative whould be to use a shared_ptr or really clarify ownership of i.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Paranaix in main thread comment, as well as @ToniBig, I can't really think of a situation where you would need this.  Such a thing is probably to protect against horrible programmer error.  You should also keep in mind that you are storing a reference to the pointer `i`, and that reference will be left dangling when the *pointer* `i` goes out of scope, regardless of whether the memory `i` refers to has been deallocated or not.  SO in conclusion, please don't do this.

Answer (score 1):

All you've done is trade one lifetime problem for another.  The new problem may be easier to solve... or it may not.

Now you can detect that the object is gone... as long as something has kept the pointer variable alive.

Think carefully about your variable lifetimes, and whether a reference-to-pointer (or equivalently, pointer to pointer) makes sense should become clear.

There certainly are cases where double indirection is valuable.  I will leave you with a quote: ["Any problem in computer science can be solved by adding another layer of indirection"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2057503/103167)

Answer (score 1):

These are options :

- give ownership to class and manage lifecycle inside it.plus with safe
  setter method for changing it when you want. Again do it if you have to create or obtain that pointer outside,otherwise just do all inside.
- only pass that pointer to methods that will use it and when
  needed.`void run(int* i)`.